# How can Spring Eureka client check local Eureka Server first, then fallback to deployed Server if no local instance registered

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have a microservices architecture. I have 1 instance of each service running on a remote and registered with Eureka successfully. I want to run the few services locally which I have made changes to. Is it possible to have my eureka clients choose the local instance over the deployed instance when multiple are available, and similarly to fall back to the deployed instance when there is no local instance of a given microservice registered with the eureka server?

Not sure if the best approach here is to have a single eureka server and both the remote and local instances register against this, or if it is better to have a remote eureka server and a local eureka server, and when the local does not have a registered instance I am looking for, my client then queries the remote Eureka server?

For any service calls in the remote environment, these should only go to the remote instances and not to the local instances I am running for any service

I have tried looking at Eureka zones, but this all seems to involve both the remote and the local eureka servers being aware of each other

Comment: Yes, you'd typically have Eureka servers that are peers. You may want to look at using zoned-loadbalancing with your Eureka client (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/reference/spring-cloud-commons/loadbalancer.html#zone-based-load-balancing) and have both Eureka servers be peers in different zones (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/reference/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_zones). If you're just running it for tests, you can also register all instances with one server. The multiple server instances are typically used for resilience in production.

Comment: But ideally I don’t want to configure the remote server to need to know about any local eureka servers running. Eg if another user starts running services locally, I don’t want to have to change the dev eureka config to now know the details of this new user’s eureka instance. Is this possible?

Comment: Generally, you'd either have a Eureka replication (so various instances running as peers) or you'd have a single instance where all your service instances register.